# How to implement paging in "with" bindings in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a requirements in my project where I need to put my selected item in the Modal and user can click next to show the next item.

I am using a with binding to display the content of selected in a form.  I don't have an idea on how can I apply paging inside a "With" binding.

```
<div class="container" data-bind="with: itemForEditing">
 <div id="riskRegisterForm" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header" style="background:#4bafef; height: 30px;">            
        <h5 style="color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Arial;">Item</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="background:#fff">
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="itemName">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="itemName" data-bind="value: name" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="itemPrice">Price</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="number" step=".01" id="itemPrice" data-bind="value: price" />
                </div>
              </div>                    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" data-bind="click:$parent.revertItem">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" data-bind="click:$parent.acceptItem">Update</button>            
    </div>
    <span><a href=#>next</a></span>
    <span><a href=#>prev</a></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

when I click the next it should autmatically select the  next records and put in the contorls. Here is the JsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ramon26cruz/Tt96J/6/

Comment: why not create a next and prev method in your viewmodel, then when an item is slected store a reference to the index.  Then when the next or prev is clicked increment or decrement the index and set the selectedItem property as the item in the array at that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="with: itemForEditing">
    <!-- ... -->
    <span><a href=# data-bind="click: $root.nextItem">next</a></span>
    <span><a href=# data-bind="click: $root.prevItem">prev</a></span>
</div>
```

and

```
ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    // offset the selected item by a certain amount (i.e. -1/+1 for next/prev)
    offsetItem: function (by) {
        var items = this.items(),
            i = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(items, this.selectedItem()),
            newItem = (i > -1) ? items[i + by] : null;

        if (newItem) {
            this.selectItem(newItem);
        }
    },
    prevItem: function () {
        this.offsetItem(-1);
    },
    nextItem: function () {
        this.offsetItem(1);
    },
    /* ... */
}
```

See it live http://jsfiddle.net/Tt96J/11/

Answer (score 2):

I've had a go at this.  I changed my tack from above.  Basically I created 2 method, a next and a prev.  In the methods I find the index of the selected / editable object in the array and the either increment or decrement based on which method has been used.  I then update the selected and editable property objects:

```
var Item = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.price = ko.observable();
    
    //populate our model with the initial data
    this.update(data);
};

//can pass fresh data to this function at anytime to apply updates or revert to a prior version
Item.prototype.update = function(data) { 
    this.name(data.name || "new item");
    this.price(data.price || 0);
};

var ViewModel = function(items) {
    this.index = 0;
    
    //turn the raw items into Item objects
    this.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(data) {
        return new Item(data);
    }));
    
    //hold the currently selected item
    this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    
    //make edits to a copy
    this.itemForEditing = ko.observable();
    
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    this.acceptItem = this.acceptItem.bind(this);
    this.revertItem = this.revertItem.bind(this);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);
};

ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    //select an item and make a copy of it for editing
    selectItem: function(item) {
        this.selectedItem(item);
        this.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(item)));
    },
    
    next:function(){
        var pos = this.items.indexOf(this.selectedItem()) + 1;
        if(pos > this.items().length - 1){pos = 0};
        
        this.selectedItem(this.items()[pos]);
        this.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(this.items()[pos])));
    },
    
    prev:function(){
        var pos = this.items.indexOf(this.selectedItem()) - 1;
        if(pos < 0){pos = this.items().length - 1};
        
        this.selectedItem(this.items()[pos]);
        this.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(this.items()[pos])));
    },
    
    acceptItem: function(item) {
        var selected = this.selectedItem(),
            edited = ko.toJS(this.itemForEditing()); //clean copy of edited
        
        //apply updates from the edited item to the selected item
        selected.update(edited);
        
        //clear selected item
        this.selectedItem(null);
        this.itemForEditing(null);
    },
    
    //just throw away the edited item and clear the selected observables
    revertItem: function() {
        this.selectedItem(null);
        this.itemForEditing(null);
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([
    { name: "Cheese", price: 2.50 },
    { name: "Pepperoni", price: 3.25 },
    { name: "Deluxe", price: 4.25 }
]));
```

Here's a link to my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/Tt96J/8/).